# What is the best JavaScript image processing library?

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I need some kick-ass effects for my web site, like gaussian blur, noise, convolution filters, morphological operations etc.
All effects must be applied dynamically (no pre-renderend images) and being changed over time.

What is the most powerful image processing library, implemented in JavaScript ?

Comment: I'm not sure about all that image processing, but perhaps you find something in the processing community. http://processing.org/reference/

Answer (score 16):

[CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/) is the most flexible non-interactive (API, not point-and-click) JavaScript library for image manipulation, that I came across so far.

Comment: +1 As of now (July 2013) Caman has a much more active development cycle than Pixastic, which hasn't been updated in 5 months. Which may or may not mean anything, just sayin'.

Comment: If it doesn't do resizing, I'd say it's not a true image processing library.

Answer (score 9):

Try to look to the [Processing.js library](http://processingjs.org/).
This is a quotation from theirs site:

> Processing.js is the sister project of
>   the popular Processing visual
>   programming language, designed for the
>   web.

As far as I know it has more contributors than Pixastic project does and theirs [demos](http://processingjs.org/exhibition) are really promising.

Comment: But Processing, despite its name, is not an image processing library, it is a graphical engine.

Comment: @Yves I think that's unfair. Processing is a media programming framework and environment that integrates graphics and image processing libraries.

Comment: Processing.js is unmaintained for many years now.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/)

> Pixastic is an experimental library which allows you to perform a variety of operations on images using just a bit of JavaScript. The effects supported out of the box include desaturation/greyscale, invert, flipping, brightness/contrast adjustment, hue/saturation, emboss, blur, and many more.

Demo can be found [here](http://editor.pixastic.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I have also found this library. But thought, that there is some other, that i did't found.

Comment: The link goes to a gambling website. The source code of the project seems to be [here](https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic), but it has not been updated since 2014.

Answer (score 3):

have a look at the [PSX](https://github.com/zhijie/psx) imageprocessing library, it contains a javascript and ios version.
the [demo site](http://toys.lzhj.me/psx/) shows what it can do.
PSX is the most powerful javascript image processing library ever.

Comment: Some nice effects but lack of documentation and unit tests is a real problem. If I want to do some local mean filters for example there's no way to know how without reading the entire source.