# Titanium Image Processing

Tags: image-processing, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules, hue

I am currently working on Appcelerator (Titanium) and now I want colorize image in APP. Like I have an image and I can able to change its color through Hue or saturation just like in Photoshop. I have searched too many things but still nothing found in working condition.
Any help would be highly appreciable

Comment: Probably your only solution is to create a module, the hard part is [already done for you.](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Answer (score -2):

Probably the best architecture is to [create a webview](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Integrating_Web_Content) in which you have a canvas tag, then you are able to use any canvas image manipulation library you wish. There are a number of them, but [here are a few.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351122/what-is-the-best-javascript-image-processing-library)

Comment: Performance of image processing in Titanium through WebView would be horrible. It's better to try modifying it using Titanium.Blob or integrating native library.