# Image Editing For Web Application

Tags: javascript, java, html, image

Requirement is user will upload the image in my application. And Later in some stage, user will view the image in the browser. And he should be able to draw simple shapes like arrow, circle ,write some text on it and again save the image back in my server. I want editing to happen at client side with any image editing open source software. Any suggestion or ideas appreciated.

Comment: look java-script image processing library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351122/what-is-the-best-javascript-image-processing-library

Comment: HTML5 Canvas could eventually be also useful: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/ and http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

Comment: Image will be in my server. Using Html Canvas can i edit the image and replace it back in the server?